# OpenGL Fog effect changes when I move or rotate the camera

Tags: opengl, fog

I want to add fog to a small 3D world, I tried fiddling with the arguments, however, the fog is not homogeneous.

I have two problems that are maybe linked :

1. Fog Homogeneity:
   When I move or rotate my viewpoint with gluLookAt, the fog is too heavy and all the world is grey.However the are two angles where the rendering of the fog is nice.
   The fog seems normal when the camera orentation on the Y axis is 45° or -135° (opposite)
2. Fog centered on origin of the scene:

When my fog is correctly displayed, it is centered on the (0;0;0) of the scene

Here is the code I use to initialise the fog and the call to gluLookAt

```
private static final float density = 1f;

private void initFog() {
    float[] vertices = {0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1f};

    ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16);
    temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());   
    FloatBuffer fogColor = temp.asFloatBuffer(); 
    fogColor.put(vertices);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.8f,0.8f,0.8f,1.0f); 
    GL11.glFogi(GL11.GL_FOG_MODE, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glFog(GL11.GL_FOG_COLOR, temp.asFloatBuffer());
    GL11.glFogf(GL11.GL_FOG_DENSITY, density);
    GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_FOG_HINT, GL11.GL_FASTEST);
    GL11.glFogf(GL11.GL_FOG_START, 1f);
    GL11.glFogf(GL11.GL_FOG_END, 10000f);
}

private void initWindow() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1600, 900));
        Display.create();
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(60f, 1600f / 900f, 3, 100000);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_FOG);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        initFog();
        initParticles();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Called from the updatePosition function inside main loop
The angle parameter is the direction of the viewport on y axis and yCpos is a value between -1 and 1 that I use to look up or down.

```
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(xpos, ypos, zpos, xpos + (float)Math.cos(angle), ypos+ yCpos, zpos+ (float)Math.sin(angle), 0, 1, 0);
```

Comment: This sounds highly unusual - linear fixed-function fog is simply a function of eye-space depth and the values of the fog range (i.e. ''end'' and ''start''). The orientation of the camera shouldn't influence the perceived density of the fog - translation, of course will change appearance of objects, but rotation alone doesn't change the distance to the camera. Can you add some screen-shots?

Comment: Are you sure you're applying `gluLookAt (...)` while the matrix mode is `GL_MODELVIEW`? Fog is one of the things that applying the viewing transformation to the PROJECTION matrix actually makes a difference for. Often if you use an identity ModelView matrix you can get away with applying the camera transform to your projection matrix, but a handful of things (fog, vertex lighting, perspective texture mapping, etc.) are screwed up if you do this.

Comment: I have the same problem and the sequence I'm using is roughly: `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); glFrustum(...); glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity(); gluLookAt(...);` (which should be fine, I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was drawing the ground with one giant quad, and now I draw the ground with tiles, and the problem isn't happening any more. Therefore, the cause remains mysterious, but the problem is solved.

Comment: I *think* I know why this is happening. It seems to have something to do with the vertices being *behind* the camera. Maybe the single large quad/triangle (or one of its vertices) is being clipped, therefore screwing up the depth interpolation used in the fog calculation.

Comment: I struggled with this problem for a LONG time. It is indeed a problem with using a single giant quad, because all its vertices are invisible from the point of view. To make it worse, the problem is graphics card and driver dependant. With my nvidia card, under ubuntu, I have this problem using the free nouveau driver. But if I switch to propietary driver, the problem is gone. 
**Using just 4 giant quads, so that each has one vertex in the center, completely solves the problem.** This seems to work with any driver.

Comment: @LGenzelis, that was exactly my case here, with the same problem faced by OP. I have a laptop with an integrated Intel processor and an NVidia card. Running the program with the Intel processor, I had the fog-depends-on-the-camera issue. Running it with the NVidia card, fog worked just as expected.